Idempotent Writing In Spring Batch
Let's assume our job-process like:

Read from CSV with chunks
Write to Message-Queue

We have a large CSV file. when we execute this CSV file, our process is terminated somehow. So we sent some of CSV rows to Message-Queue but some of them couldn't. In this case, I can re-run my job but in this case, some CSV rows will be duplicated in Message-Queue. Is there a way to prevent it?

Spring Batch supports restart of the same Job Instance after failure. It will resume the process.
For that, you need to configure beans JobOperator and JobExplorer, retrieve the job id and launch it with the JobOperator restart
